# keep getting this errror :" Cast to ObjectId failed for value" using mongodb with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to coding and trying to build an APi using NOde js, express and mongodb

here is my code

```
router.get('/:id', async(req, res) => {  
console.log(req.params.id);
try{    
        const show = await Show.findById(req.params.id);
        const _iD = show._id.toHexString()
        console.log(_iD );
        if(req.params.id === _iD){
        res.json(show);      
        } else {
            res.send("not right ID");
        }
}

catch(err){
    console.log("error" + err)
}
})
```

it not working out,if "you enter a wrong ID intentionally " and should get " not right ID ", but it gets "Cast to Object ID failed for value".

Answer (score 0):

Try out this function

```
function isMongooseId(id) {
    var valid = false;
    try{
        if(id == mongoose.Types.ObjectId(""+id)) valid = true;
    } catch(e){
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}

// You can use it like this,

if(isMongooseId(req.params.id)) {
    // Perform your db operation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "intentionally wrong ID" still respect the objectId syntax (24 hexadecimal characters i would say). Otherwise you will fail at the `Show.findById` and jump right into the `catch`.

Then, i'm not sure of what your trying to do.

If you provide an ID that is not present in the collection, `Show.findById` will not return any object so you won't be able to get its ID with `show._id.toHexString()` and you will, again, jump to the `catch`.

And if the ID is in the collection, `req.params.id === _iD` will always be true and you will never reach the else.

Instead you should just check if show contain an object